# receive and delete message in a while loop on aws

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a code like this written in node.js for aws applications. I'm familiar with java and python but not with javascript.

I need to check if i have any messages left in my queue and if so i need to proccess them then delete. But as far as i understand the while loop doesn't wait for my queue processes and just run. After some time it exhausts my memory.

If i do it with for loop then no problem  but i must  do this with while loop so is there any way to use while loop for this?

```
message_count = true;



while (message_count === true)
{
    queue.getQueueAttributes(params_queue, function (err, data)
    {
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        else
            console.log(data);
        if (data.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages == "0")
        {
            message_count = false;
        }
        queue.receiveMessage(function (err, data)
        {
            if (data)
            {
                message = data.Messages[0].Body
                receipthandle = data.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle;
                params.ReceiptHandle = receipthandle
                queue.deleteMessage(params, function (err, data)
                {
                    if (err)
                        console.log(err, err.stack);
                    else
                        console.log(data);

                });
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify, how is it not a problem with a for loop? And you are using while loop already.. what do u want to change?

Comment: This while loop doesn't work somehow (skipping all the queue parts and just runs off with while true) and if i use a for loop and set message number as my endpoint, it gives all the messages i want. Every post i looked suggests changing while loop to recursive or for loop.

Comment: What there are no more messages in the queue? do you not want to resume consumption of messages at some point?

Answer (score 10):

Here is some sample code I wrote sometime back to consume messages from queue. And when there are no messages try again after 1 minute delay.

```html
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var sqs = new AWS.SQS();
var sqsQueueURl = "<queueurl>";

var receiveMessageParams = {
    QueueUrl : sqsQueueURl,
    MaxNumberOfMessages : 10,
    VisibilityTimeout : 10,
    WaitTimeSeconds : 10
};

var receiveMessage = function() {
    sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageParams, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            }
        if (data.Messages) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Messages.length; i++) {
                var message = data.Messages[i];
                var body = JSON.parse(message.Body);
                // execute logic
                removeFromQueue(message);
            }
            receiveMessage();
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                receiveMessage()
            }, 60 * 1000);

        }
    });
};

var removeFromQueue = function(message) {
    sqs.deleteMessage({
        QueueUrl : sqsQueueURl,
        ReceiptHandle : message.ReceiptHandle
    }, function(err, data) {
        err && console.log(err);
    });
};


receiveMessage();
```

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question but thank you for your time

Comment: exactly, i simply wanted to receive one message, proccess it and have something run on the instance according with the message and as soon as the proccessing is finished, get another message and do the same.
And i wondered why it didn't work with while loop

Comment: because nodejs works asynchronously and the 2nd fetch does not wait for the 1st fetch to complete, i.e. the for loop continues to the next iteration, when the 1st iteration fetch is not complete. You may need to use packages like deasync in node to make the operation behave synchronous.

Comment: how about using events and calling recursions event based?

Comment: SQS does not support events, its not a full fledge messaging service like rabbitmq or activemq. The only option you have is polling.